# Task.Run with cancellation support

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Consider [this `Task.Run` example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160373%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It shows how to create a task with cancellation support.

I am doing something similar:

```
Task.Run(()=>{while (!token.IsCancellationRequested()) {...}}, token);
```

My questions:

1. Since I already have a reference to the cancellation token, why the purpose of passing it as a parameter to the `Task.Run` invocation?
2. I often see the following code in examples:

   `if (token.IsCancellationRequested) token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`

What's the purpose of this code? Why not just `return` from the method?

Comment: I was just about the answer but Sriram's answer covers it. But you don't have to use `if (token.IsCancellationRequested) ...` since `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` already checks that.

Comment: @Dirk I just covered that also :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If you pass the cancellation token to `Task.Run`, if the token is cancelled before the Task is started, it will never be started saving you resources(I mean by not creating threads etc).
2. If you just return from the method, the Task's Status will not be `Canceled`, it will be `RanToCompletion`. Clearly this isn't what you'll expect.

Alternatively you could throw `OperationCanceledException` with the `CancellationToken` as parameter, that will make the `Task.Status` to be `Canceled`, but this is the hard and verbose way. `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` is concise.

You could simply use `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`, no need to check for `token.IsCancellationRequested`. `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` method already does this.

Comment: Good answer, just one question: ThrowIfCancellationRequested throws an error, if this happens. Isn't it bad practice to use exceptions for workflow handling?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller Good question. But cancellation isn't a normal control flow right? It means you are not interested in the started Task. Designers of BCL has chosen to use exceptions for this purpose to convey the cancellation. Just like you going to a hotel, ordered something which took a long time to serve, you can't wait anymore and said *I don't need that crap anymore. Cancel it!*  As this isn't a usual thing, they have chosen to use exceptions is my guess. Otherwise, you need flags, If there are nested method calls you can't handle it easily. Can you see what I mean?